# Essential Firefox Plugins/Extensions?

Tags: firefox

What firefox plugins could you not live without, as relates to webdev?

My list would be:

- [DBGBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3227)
- [Dom Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/6622)
- Firebug
- [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683)
- Google toolbar (useful for seo)
- Live HTTP
- [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/115)
- TamperData
- Web Developer

I am always on the lookout for new ones though, so I wonder if anyone knows of any great ones that I may have missed?

Answer (score 17):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is the main one I use.

Comment: a link would be handy for those who don't already have it

Comment: Here you go! http://is.gd/4s8KN  ;)

Comment: (I know, I know... not funny ;) )

Answer (score 10):

[Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/60) is quite useful ([firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/1843) Andrew mentions is no doubt #1)

Answer (score 6):

IETab is a nice to have (IE in a Firefox  Tab)

Comment: This is excellent for quickly checking a layout in IE. It uses the installed version of IE for its rendering.

Answer (score 6):

No mention of [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) or Mason?

Comment: Greasemonkey is a must have in my book.

Answer (score 5):

[Live HTTP headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829), in addition to some already mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

NoScript. Not just for blocking spam - it's a lot quicker than flipping the script setting on and off manually, and lets you simulate third-party servers going down.

You can also get a lot of useful info just from Firefox's built in error console (in the Tools menu) - among other things it'll point out broken CSS code.

Comment: You can disable all javascript using Web Developer toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

[YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369) - analyzes web pages and tells you why they're slow.

[MeasureIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/539) - Draw out a ruler to get the pixel width and height of any elements on a webpage. Even better is the [Xray bookmarklet](http://www.westciv.com/xray/).

[Hackbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3899) Simple security audit / Penetration test tool.

[FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6149) is a Firebug extension for AJAX Development

[ColorZilla 2.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271) is an advanced eyedropper, colorpicker, page zoomer and some other things.

Comment: If you already use the Web Developer add-on, it does have a ruler buried in it's options somewhere.  I use to have MeasureIt installed before I discovered this.

Answer (score 3):

[TestGen4Web](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1385) - Just like your VCR - for Firefox. It records what you do, stores it, and plays it back on demand.

Answer (score 3):

the [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249) plugin is priceless, especially when you're working on stuff written by someone else who may not be so careful with standards compliance...

Answer (score 2):

Firebug, Web Developer toolbar and YSlow for Firebug are some of my picks.

Answer (score 1):

[ff-activex](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/) - allows to use active-x plug-ins in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I (ab)use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) to experiment with/prototype css changes. Yes you can do it in Firebug but it's not easy to keep track of all the edits you've made and it's not easy to copy & paste those edits back into your css file. Also, if you hit F5 you lose all changes made in Firebug.

[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) survives page refresh and since it's just text you can simply select all to copy & paste your changes. Of course, it doesn't provide a css inspector or a DOM tree view but that's what Firebug is for.

Answer (score 0):

- Web Developer
- Firebug
- Delicious

Might also add Page Validator

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is the greatest.

Also, not a dev tool but I have found it very useful and easy to use, [Foxmarks](http://foxmarks.com) bookmark manager.

Answer (score 0):

Two other ones that I use are ...

1. Search Status (SEO related) http://www.quirk.biz/searchstatus/
2. Ad Block Plus (Blocks Ads) http://adblockplus.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

Many of my favourites have been mentioned. To these I'd add:

- Adblock Plus: removes ads
- Add-Art: replaces ads with art
- Auto Copy: copies to clipboard on select
- Tree-Style Tab: shows tabs like a tree

Answer (score 0):

Some of my favorites among others which already mentioned ,

- TabKit - Shows tabs in separate panel
  , closes the tabs in groups ,
  grouping of tabs.
- Morning Coffee -    restore the tabs
  those are saved to    view them
  later.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Undo closed tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3082). This is what I miss from IE8.
2. [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109), for backing up the settings of Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already mentioned addins:

- [ViewState](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/5956) - Displays the current ASP.NET page viewstate size in the status bar.
- [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) - Advanced Eyedropper, Color Picker, Palette Viewer and other colorful goodies for your Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Besides the ones already mentioned (especially the marvellous [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/)), these are the *development related* ones I've found very useful:

- [JSONovich](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10122) does a good job at pretty-printing and colorizing JSON.
- [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) is very handy for developing mobile web sites (or just for the sake of curiosity) -- "I'm an iPhone, reveal me your contents!"
- Sometimes Firefox leaves stuff in the browser cache even on reloads. The [Clear Cache Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1801) helps with this.
- [Header Spy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4276) is similar to Live HTTP headers, but displays header information (and access to lots of more options) in the statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Another one I use a fair amount is the [Amazon S3 Firefox Organizer (S3Fox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3247)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those already mentioned, [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Venkman](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/) to be useful recently, in addition to firebug and others already mentioned.

> Venkman aims to provide a powerful JavaScript debugging environment for Gecko-based browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I find it interesting that so many people name a significant number of addons that Web Developer toolbar does for you. While they are all great plugins and might have a couple extra options, not sure if its worth it to have those plugins (for instance, MeasureIt)

Here is my list:
 - **Web Developer Toolbar** (if you're a web developer [period])
 - **FireBug** (essential for javascript/AJAX debugging)
 - **Google Page Speed** (similar to YSLOW but it's from Google, very useful)
 - **ColorZilla** (great color picker)
 - **HTML Validator** (saves a bunch of time loading w3.org's page)
 - **Tab Mix Plus** (anything and everything to do with tabbed browsing)
 - **Screengrab** (if you use screenshots at all, use this)
 - **Google Toolbar** (SEO)

Answer (score 0):

My list of addons which I use for development is:

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/)
- [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/)
- [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/)
- [Pinger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10201/)

I think those are essential for proper web development.